# Move "VirtualBox VMs" folder

Tags: virtualbox

I moved virtualbox folder from the Home to somewhere else, but when I run the virtualbox, my "virtual machine is inacessible". I tryed "Import appliance" again, change the settings and some other stuff, but it did not work.
How can I correctly move this folder?

Answer (score 2):

This is from my own documentation after trial and error a while ago, I hope it makes sense to you. The "--" is optional in case of problems but maybe it also helps you with your present situation...:

- when moving virtual machine, use FILE/VIRTUAL MEDIA MANAGER, first release HDD and then remove via FILE/Virtual Media Manager (but do NOT delete files when removing)
- move the machine folders to the new location
- add the removed virtual machine from new location via MACHINE/ADD
- right click on virtual machine and go to  SETTINGS/STORAGE: click on first controller (Guest additions should already be there) and add (first small button) hard disk (as attachment) > choose existing disk  and then check SSD if necessary

--  if you cannot add add a HDD with the first small button (Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)) do as described here: http://bradleybeddoes.com/2011/08/01/virtualbox-vd-error-verr_file_not_found-opening-image-file/

-- Virtual Media Manager, click on Hard drives > open sub entry under X.vdi image named like {a2abf38f-3526... and RELEASE then REMOVE it